# Ubuntu 16.04 is not detecting external displays

Tags: drivers, upgrade, 16.04, multiple-monitors, display

I upgraded to 16.04, but my Dell XPS 13 is not detecting my 2 external monitors.

I am using a Dell Display Link that was working on when I was on 14.04.
I have 2 monitors, my keyboard and my mouse plugged into the Display Link. My mouse and keyboard work fine.

Here is some commands and their output:

```
uname -a
Linux luke-XPS-13-9343 4.5.1-040501-generic #201604121331 SMP Tue Apr 12 17:33:29 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

sudo lshw -C display
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I appreciate the help. Feel free to ask for more info, but don't be surprised if I ask you what commands I need to run to get it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a dummy. All I had to do was install the display link video drivers. 
Instructions can be found [here](http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu).

In short:

1. Download the drivers [here](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu). (Happily, 16.04 is supported).
2. Extract the zipfile. The zip file contains a license and a single shell script named `displaylink-driver-[version number].run`
3. Give the file execute priviliges via `chmod a+x [filename]`
4. Execute the file via `sh`.

With any luck you should be able to plug right in with no restart necessary.